# Saying "Thank You" to Govt Employees

Tags: work-environment, ethics, government

In my country, Government employees are unfortunately known for their *laidback approach* and delayed output. Yesterday I had to visit a government bank for some documentation and account opening. After some 2 hours (waste of time!), I finally opened my account and got the relevant information. At the end, I said 'Thank you' to the staff who was handling my account opening and documentation requests, despite the delay. My friend had accompanied me to the visit too. He told that one should not say 'Thank you' to them because of the following reasons:

1. They intentionally delay the process and are lazy.
2. They're anyways supposed to do their work quickly and their job is to assist the incoming customers in relevant issues.
3. They will expect every other person after myself to say 'Thank you' at the end and this will increase their bias towards those who don't say 'Thank you' or compliment them for any reason whatsoever.

I responded by saying that not all govt employees are of that kind and maybe saying 'Thank you' out of kind heart will make their day and stimulate their work productivity. Also would not the personal touch would make us more *human*? This got me thinking and I wish to know if there is a strong reason to thank/compliment or to not compliment the Government/Official staff service whenever I visit any such place next time?

Comment: “They're anyways supposed to do their work quickly and their job is to assist the incoming customers in relevant issues.” - This can be said by anyone doing their job. Your friend sounds like they are ungrateful and general an unhappy person. The fact the person doing their job is a government employee has little to do with your question.  The person could have been a stable cleaner, and if they did a task that you thanked them for, your friend would be equally ungrateful and unpleasant

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about interpersonal interactions in general rather than interactions within a workplace

Answer (score 8):

> I wish to know if there is a strong reason to thank/compliment

Sure, you don't even have to do it for them. You can do it just for the sake of having good manners. I thank most people just because I was brought up to do so and it costs me nothing. And if my kids are with me it's creating an example for them to follow.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a case of the "[Waiter Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waiter_Rule)" in action, good manners don't cost anything and can be beneficial both to the person giving and recieving. Conversely being rude can even bring *negative* consequences back on the rude person, something your friend actually understands:

> They will expect every other person after myself to say 'Thank you' at the end and this will increase their bias towards those who don't say 'Thank you' or compliment them for any reason whatsoever.

The fact that your friend would rather *you* were equally rude as they are in a clumsy attempt to avoid those consequences instead of just doing better themselves is.. interesting.

> I responded by saying that not all govt employees are of that kind and maybe saying 'Thank you' out of kind heart will make their day and stimulate their work productivity. Also would not the personal touch would make us more human? This got me thinking and I wish to know if there is a strong reason to thank/compliment or to not compliment the Government/Official staff service whenever I visit any such place next time?

You're spot on, and the fact that these people are government employees is completely irrelevant, it makes no difference to the fact that they're still your fellow human beings.